# Can anyone suggest how to do an animation effect like Standard Refresh button do in Lightning Component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, button

In standard related lists, (for example) `Contacts` related list on an `Account` record. If we open full list and click on `Refresh` button, it happens to do an animated effect by rotating the icon inside the button.

Can anyone suggest how to do that in a custom component with a lightning button/buttonIcon?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is created via following css class:

```
.forceListViewManagerHeader .rotate svg {
animation: rotate .4s;
}
```

Check the screenshot also

[image: css for rotation]